# how to retain the leading "00" when incrementing a value

Tags: python

I want to retain the leading "00" when a value is incremented by one,below val has "00349",when i increment and print
it becomes 350,how to print as 00350 retaining the leading "00"

```
val = 00349
val = val + 1
print val -->prints as 350,i want to print as 00350
```

Comment: It probably is, if you know what to look for. For people starting to program, "padding" might be the word they're missing.

Comment: Also note that this code breaks in python2. A number starting in `0` is considered in octal, and you have a 9 that is impossible. `val = 0034; print val --> 28`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to print the number using a format string:

```
print "%05d" % val
```

Also, be aware that by storing a number with a leading zero, you store it as an octal number:

```
>>> val = 0123
>>> print val
83
```